# Cantor-Bernstein theorem proof - Hrbacek and Jech textbook

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I have worked through a proof of the Cantor-Bernstein theorem as presented in Hrbacek and Jech's *Introduction to Set Theory* third edition. It makes use of a Lemma:

> If $A_1 \subseteq B \subseteq A$ and $|A_1|=|A|$, then $|B|=|A|$.

The Lemma is fine - I have no problem with that - but in the main part of the proof the following statement is made:

> Clearly $g[f[X]] \subseteq g[Y] \subseteq X$; moreover, since $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one, we have $|X|=|g[f[X]]|$ and $|Y|=|g[Y]|$.

with the functions $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow X$ associated with the given hypothesis that $|X|\leq|Y|$ and $|Y|\leq|X|$. So to me it is not clear on a rigorous level why $|X|=g[f[X]]$ simply because both $g$ and $f$ are one-to-one? How would one go about proving this part rigorously?

What makes the most sense to me on an intuitive level is that $f^{-1}(f(X))=X$ since $f$ is one-to-one, and then since $g$ is also one-to-one and the domain of $g$ contains $f(X)$ and the range of $g$ is contained in $X$ we must therefore have that $g(f(X))$ also equals $X$. This boils down to the statement: If we have two one-to-one functions $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $g:A \rightarrow B$ and we have $f(A)=B$ then we must have $g(A)=B$. It seems obvious, but somehow not rigorous enough?

Any comments or help will be much appreciated...

Comment: Since $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one, so is $g\circ f$, and $|X|=\left|(g\circ f)[X]\right|$ by definition. All that you need here is the fact that a composition of one-to-one functions is one-to-one.

Comment: ah ok, so if I see $(g \circ f):X \rightarrow (g \circ f)[X]$ as a single one-to-one function then obviously it is onto...something tells me I've been overthinking this...probably time to go to sleep...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\colon X\to Y$ is an injective function, then it is a bijection between $X$ and $\operatorname{rng}(f)$, of $f[X]$, since every function is onto its range by definition.

Since the restriction of $g$, an injective function, to $f[X]$, is still an injective function, the same argument applies, and $g$ is a bijection between $f[X]$ and $g[f[X]]$. Since composing bijections is a bijection, it shows that $g[f[X]]$ and $X$ have the same cardinality and $g\circ f$ is a witnessing bijection.

Comment: Thanks yes...I just needed to see $(g \circ f)$ as a single one-to-one function which is obviously onto its range...thanks!